# Python Превратить дерево (словарь) в "хлебные крошки"

Tags: python, массивы, dict, breadcrumbs, словарь

Вот пример словаря. Он хранит категории магазина, если у категории есть вложенные категории, то они помещаются в children:

```
{
  'Бытовая техника': {
    'url': 'http://some-url.com',
    'children': {
      'Утюги': {
      'url': 'http://some-url.com',
      'children': {
          'Паровые утюги': {
              'url': 'http://some-url.com',
          }
      }
      },
    }
  },
  'Автоуход': {
    'url': 'http://какая-то ссылка'
  }
}
```

и так далее.

Мне же нужно привести это к следующему виду:

```
{
  'Бытовая техника': 'http://some-url.com',
  'Бытовая техника > Утюги': 'http://some-url.com',
  'Бытовая техника > Утюги -> Паровые утюги': 'http://some-url.com',
  'Автоуход': 'http://some-url.com'
}
```

Моя неудачная попытка:

```
bread_crumbs = {}
def parse_cats(categories_dict, parent='Отсутствует'):
    for k in categories_dict:
        print(parent,' > ', k)
        bread_crumbs['%s > %s}' % (parent, k)] = categories_dict[k]
        if categories_dict[k].__contains__('children'):
            parse_cats(categories_dict[k]['children'], k)
```

Функция выводит следующее:

```
Бытовая техника
Бытовая техника  >  Утюги
Утюги  >  Паровые утюги
Автоуход
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересная задачка.

---

### Входные данные:

Немного изменил для наглядности при отладке.

```py
d = {
    'Бытовая техника': {
        'url': 'http://byt.com',
        'children': {
            'Утюги': {
                'url': 'http://utug.com',
                'children': {
                    'Паровые утюги': {
                        'url': 'http://par.com',
                    },
                    'ДВС утюги': {
                        'url': 'http://dvs.com',
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    'Автоуход': {
        'url': 'http://auto.com',
        'children': {
            'Стёкла': {
                'url': 'http://stekla.com',
            },
            'Фары': {
                'url': 'http://fary.com'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Решение:

```py
def iter_chains(base_dict: dict, curr_chain: list=[]) -> tuple:
    for category, subdict in base_dict.items():
        new_chain = curr_chain.copy()
        new_chain.append(category)
        yield " > ".join(new_chain), subdict["url"]
        if subdict.get("children") is not None:
            yield from iter_chains(subdict["children"], new_chain)


bread_crumbs = {chain: url for chain, url in iter_chains(d)}

import json 
print(json.dumps(bread_crumbs, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

### Вывод:

```
{
    "Бытовая техника": "http://byt.com",
    "Бытовая техника > Утюги": "http://utug.com",
    "Бытовая техника > Утюги > Паровые утюги": "http://par.com",
    "Бытовая техника > Утюги > ДВС утюги": "http://dvs.com",
    "Автоуход": "http://auto.com",
    "Автоуход > Стёкла": "http://stekla.com",
    "Автоуход > Фары": "http://fary.com"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Держи, дружище)

```
# словарь с деревом ссылок
dict = {
    'Бытовая техника': {
        'url': 'http://some-url.com',
        'children': {
            'Утюги': {
                'url': 'http://some-url.com',
                'children': {
                    'Паровые утюги': {
                        'url': 'http://some-url.com',
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    'Автоуход': {
        'url': 'http://какая-то ссылка'
    }
}

# словарь-результат
result = {}

# рекурсивная функция преобразования
def breadcrumbs(dictionary, string = ''):
    # локальный результат работы функции (результат на этом уровне)
    result = {}
    for key in dictionary:
        # добавляем ссылку в словарь
        # strip используется довольно костыльно, чтобы не было > в начале строки
        result.update( {(string + ' > ' + key).strip('> '): dictionary[key]['url']} )

        # если есть дочерние элементы - вызываем функцию рекурсивно для дочернего элемента, результат также добавляем в result
        if dictionary[key].get('children') != None:
            result.update( breadcrumbs( dictionary[key].get('children'), (string + ' > ' + key).strip('> ') ) )
    # возвращаем объекты этого уровня и дочерних уровней
    return result

# использование функции для помещения в словарь result форматированного словаря
result.update(breadcrumbs(dict))
# проверяем, в каком виде хранятся ссылки теперь
for item in result:
    print(f'{item} : {result[item]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

я старался

```
def parse_cats(categories_dict, parent=None, grandparent=None):
    for key in categories_dict:
        if parent is None and grandparent is None:
            str_key = '{} :'.format(key)
            str_arg = categories_dict[key]['url']
            if 'children' in categories_dict[key].keys():
                parse_cats(categories_dict[key]['children'], key)
        elif parent is not None and grandparent is None:
            str_key = '{} > {} :'.format(parent, key)
            str_arg = categories_dict[key]['url']
            if 'children' in categories_dict[key].keys():
                parse_cats(categories_dict[key]['children'], key, parent)
        else:
            str_key = '{} > {} -> {} :'.format(grandparent, parent, key)
            str_arg = categories_dict[key]['url']
        bread_crumbs[str_key] = str_arg
```

а вообще, хранить что то вот так в словаре - плохая идея, на 3 уровне вложенности вы потеряете родительский список