# Как извлечь нужные ключи из огромного JSON файла с помощью Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари, dict

В общем, представьте огромный JSON: у родителя, есть много детей, у каждого ребенка неизвестное количество своих детей, у тех детей, взрослых, есть свои дети. Поэтому простым циклом не получается извлечь. Нужна видимо, рекурсия, если я хочу извлечь `need_key` у всех детей, внуков, правнуков и т.д.
Есть идея, как это реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема? Не знаете как сделать рекурсивный обход или глубины стека не хватает?

Comment: не знаю, как сделать рекурсивный обход =)

Comment: Похоже на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1052453/324059.