# Python одноуровневый словарь из многоуровневого

Tags: python, словари, dict, преобразование

Нужно сделать из многоуровневого словаря вида

```
d = {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 6,
    "c": {
        "f": 9,
        "g": {
            "m": 17,
            "n": 3
        }
    }
}
```

словарь вида

```
{
        'a': 5,
        'b': 6,
        'c.f': 9,
        'c.g.m': 17,
        'c.g.n': 3
}
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: @mrEvgenX Это нормальный вопрос, никакого "задания" тут нет — а если и есть, то оно атомарно ;)

Comment: Возможно, вас на решение задачи натолкнёт [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052453/1052463#1052463) ответ по схожей тематике - распаковка словаря. Нужно будет только немного изменить его.

Comment: [Решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1052488/324059) Вашей задачи на других входных данных.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант с рекурсией:

```
d = {"a": 5, "b": 6, "c": {"f": 9, "g": {"m": 17, "n": 3}}}

def f(d, prefix='', sep='.'):
    nd = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            nd.update(f(v, f'{prefix}{k}{sep}'))
        else:
            nd[f'{prefix}{k}'] = v
    return nd

print(f(d))  # -> {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c.f': 9, 'c.g.m': 17, 'c.g.n': 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

не кидайтесь сильно камнями. Но можно примерно так)

```
d = {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 6,
    "c": {
        "f": 9,
        "g": {
            "m": 17,
            "n": 3
        }
    }
}
new_d ={}
for k,v in d.items():
    if type(v)!=dict:
        new_d[k] = v
    else:
        for k1,v1 in v.items():
            if type(v1)!=dict:
                new_k = k+'.'+k1
                new_d[new_k] = v1
            else:
                for k2,v2 in v1.items():
                    if type(v2)!=dict:
                        new_k1 = k+'.'+k1+'.'+k2
                        new_d[new_k1] = v2                

print(new_d)
```

Comment: лучше обернуть в функцию и использовать рекурсия

Comment: @Danis да понятно, но надо же чтобы и автор вопроса что-то сделал)